# QML Date -- Storage and locale-based display

Tags: qt, date, qml, locale

How would you recommend to store a date in a database? As milliseconds? In a QML application, I can easily get this by the `Date.now()` function. However, if the date is stored as milliseconds, how could I go about displaying the date, using some of the functions of the Date QML type? This seems to be shrouded by mystery to me at this minute. I would prefer the date to be printed locale-sensitively, so that different users in different countries get the culture-specific formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was pretty simple. I guess it is ok to store the date as milliseconds, as you can simply create a new Date object from that in QML. The locale formatting functions have couple of easy variants for printing both date and time separately:

```
Text {
...
    property var dateOf: new Date(myTimeInMilliseconds)
    text: dateOf.toLocaleDateString() + "  " + dateOf.toLocaleTimeString()
}
```